# FluentValidation and IList<T> properties

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I want to pull the list validation rules into a class specific to the list, but I'm having trouble with validating that the list isn't null and isn't empty.

Here's a mockup of what I mean:

```
public class SomeAppData
{
    public IList<UserDetails> Users { get; set; } = new List<UserDetails>();
}


public class UserDetails
{
    public string UserId { get; set; } = "";
    public string RoleId { get; set; } = "";
}


public class ListOfUsersValidator : AbstractValidator<IList<UserDetails>>
{
    public ListOfUsersValidator()
    {
        // list cannot be null or empty (i.e. at least 1 user is required
        RuleFor(list => list).NotNull().NotEmpty();

        // each userid and roleid cannot be more than 50 characters long
        RuleForEach(list => list)
            .ChildRules(user => {
                user.RuleFor(x => x.UserId).MaximumLength(50);
                user.RuleFor(x => x.RoleId).MaximumLength(50);
            });
    }
}


public class SomeAppDataValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeAppData>
{
    public SomeAppDataValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Users).SetValidator(new ListOfUsersValidator);
    }
}
```

In ListOfUsersValidator, this bit of code: "RuleFor(list => list).NotNull().NotEmpty();" is ineffective. It never reports errors regardless of whether the list is null or empty.

If I make SomeAppDataValidator do the validation, see below, then it works:

```
public class SomeAppDataValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeAppData>
{
    public SomeAppDataValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Users)
            .NotNull().NotEmpty()
            .SetValidator(new ListOfUsersValidator);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Intuitively this makes sense because you would have to associate the validator with the property in question in some fashion. Also, intuitively `RuleFor(x => x.Users).SetValidator(new ListOfUsersValidator);` seems like it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful:

```
public class ListOfUsersValidator : AbstractValidator<IList<UserDetails>>
{
    public ListOfUsersValidator()
    {
        // list cannot be null or empty (i.e. at least 1 user is required
        RuleFor(list => list).NotEmpty();

        // each userid and roleid cannot be more than 50 characters long
        RuleForEach(list => list)
            .ChildRules(user => {
                user.RuleFor(x => x.UserId).MaximumLength(50);
                user.RuleFor(x => x.RoleId).MaximumLength(50);
            });
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<IList<UserDetails>> context)
    {
        return context.InstanceToValidate == null ?
            new ValidationResult(new[] { new ValidationFailure("IList<UserDetails>", "List cannot be null") }) :
            base.Validate(context);
    }
}
```

It's works with `null` list:

```
var data = new SomeAppData { Users = null };
var validator = new ListOfUsersValidator();

// results contains 1 error 'List cannot be null'
var results = validator.Validate(data.Users);

var validationSucceeded = results.IsValid; // is false
```

Comment: Not really a help. Having to explicitly invoke Validate() breaks the whole automatic property binding validation side of things (.net core mvc). Thanks though.

Comment: @IConfuseEasily I run Validate only to do the test, to try my code. You don't need to run Validate method neither create a ListOfUsersValidator. That is done automatically.